# How to render a html partial in another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, renderpartial

I need to render a simple HTML page as partial within this div.It is a simple HTML5 application, not of MVC architecture hence Html.RenderPartial is not working.Any help??

```
<div id= "this_div_will_contain_partial">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jquery's](http://api.jquery.com/load/) load:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#this_div_will_contain_partial').load('http://www.urpartialurl.com');
    });
</script>
```

I have noticed that you haven't included javascript tag but this is the only option to achieve this. Also the page you are trying to access needs to be on the same domain.